Shrink div vertically when there is less content
I want the blue div to shrink and allow the green div to take up more space when there is not much content in the blue div, and vice versa. However, neither div can become larger than 50% of the container if there is a lot of content in both divs.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.topDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="topDiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomDiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    </div>
  </div>




Can you try adding align-self: flex-start; to the blue div?

I'm seeming to recall that this can't be done with flexbox. flex-grow: 1 just means expand as much as possible... there's now way to limit it as I recall.

I don't understand. If there're only two div and neither can grow over 50% of the parent's height, mathematically it means both div are fixed to exactly 50% right? Or are you expecting to have the div to fit their content to leave gaps if the contents takes less than 50%?

Hopefully this can clarify:
If the blue div doesn't have much content, then show the blue div without the scrollbar and have the green div take up the remaining space (possibly with a scrollbar).
If the green div doesn't have much content, then show the green div without the scrollbar and have the blue div take up the remaining space (possibly with a scrollbar).
if the blue and green divs have a lot of content, split the space evenly 50/50 with both divs having scrollbars.

Yeah, pretty sure you can't do that with flexbox. One of the elements can have flex:1 not both. If they do they both get 50% of the available space. Not sure if there is a workaround.

@epatmalnieks Yes thank you for clarifying the question! Like @Paulie_D said it doesn't seem possible using flex but this is the default behavior using grid if you set overflow:auto on both child div.

@Pauilie_D as shown below, both will show scroll if both have content more than 50%, else the one without 50% will shrink.

Like Paulie_D mentioned, I'm not sure if it is possible using flex. However, this is the default behavior using the grid display if overflow:auto is set on both child div.

Top div have more content:


.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
}

.topDiv {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="topDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis.</p>
    </div>
</div>



Bottom div have more content:


.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
}

.topDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="topDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
  </div>
</div>



Both div have more content:


.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
}

.topDiv {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bottomDiv {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="topDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>  </div>
  <div class="bottomDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus eius quia a iure, odit corporis, iusto molestiae delectus dolores possimus accusantium voluptatum, nam. Unde atque veritatis quo at, in eligendi.</p>
  </div>
</div>




Also the added benefit of when there is insufficient content in either child they still take up 50% of the fixed height.

This will work, thanks everyone!
